# Excel query for finding duplicates when the given table is not a pattern

Tags: excel-formula, return-value, excelquery

I'm a beginner at Excel, I managed to solve almost all the problems encountered in the past month, but here I don't know how.

The required thing is to search in the table if there are more than a master with the same id (same name, same id) and if the attachment id is equal to the id master of it.

So, if an attached name's id is different of the same name master id, it should return "KO".

Basically, it's not allowed to have two master "things" ("names" in this example) with the same name and both to be master, if they have the same name, one should be master and the other attached to that master.

After that, it should check the attachment id of the attached name with the master's id, should it be the same.

I hope I was clear enough in explaining.

I'd really appreciate if someone who thinks this is a "newbie thing and can be done in 1 min, to make time to show me how it can be done, it would make my life a lot easier.

Thank you and have a nice day!

https://ibb.co/tDczkDm
[given example] (https://i.stack.imgur.com/ntdW9.jpg)

Comment: Have you tried using [conditional formatting](https://support.office.com/en-ie/article/use-formulas-with-conditional-formatting-fed60dfa-1d3f-4e13-9ecb-f1951ff89d7f)?

Comment: Unless I'm misunderstanding your question you just need the remove duplicates feature in the data menu: https://support.office.com/en-us/article/find-and-remove-duplicates-00e35bea-b46a-4d5d-b28e-66a552dc138d